# XPath expression to verify a date

Tags: xpath

I woud like to know if there's a way (Using XPath) to verify if `dcterms:created` has been created after May 22th 1990 ? The expression should give a match if it's the case. I've tryed several things but I can't get it to work. Ex: `//dcterms:created[text() > "1990-05-22"]` The problem is that the comparison opertors don't seem to work because the date format isn't a recognized value.

Code that I want to search:

```
<dcterms:created>1990-05-25</dcterms:created>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings, convert them first to a date type and than compare them:

```
 //dcterms:created[xs:date(text()) > xs:date("1990-05-22")]
```